# What destroys Kaam in a man?

Tags: sex, kama

Kaam (sexual and romantic desires towards women) is problematic for many men, as many men are unable to fulfill it due to various reasons. Also many people say that indulging in Kaam doesn't eliminate Kaam but fuels it ( I think Yayati said this in Mbh)

How can a man eliminate Kaam ?

Many people say that Gyaan eliminates Kaam. Many people say devotion towards god can destroy kaam.

What is written about it in scriptures ?

Comment: Here are some things that worked for me that are closely related to scriptures:- Completely eliminating any external stimulus(quit indulging), strict control on diet(eat as close to satvik food as possible),fasts, company of holy saints(discourses,kirtans etc), listening and reading abt glories and past-times of the Lord, namasmaranam and japa daily (very powerful) of the Lord/Your ishta/diety you are currently worshipping and complete surrender to them for help and grace!

Answer (score 7):

Bhagavad Gita

> > श्रीभगवानुवाच
> > असंशयं महाबाहो मनो दुर्निग्रहं चलम् ।
> > अभ्यासेन तु कौन्तेय वैराग्येण च गृह्यते ॥ ३५ ॥

> > Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa said: O mighty-armed son of Kuntī, it is undoubtedly very difficult to curb the restless mind, but it is possible by suitable practice and by detachment.

> > यतो यतो निश्चलति मनश्चञ्चलमस्थिरम् ।
> > ततस्ततो नियम्यैतदात्मन्येव वशं नयेत् ॥ २६ ॥

> > From wherever the mind wanders due to its flickering and unsteady nature, one must certainly withdraw it and bring it back under the control of the Self.

> > विषया विनिवर्तन्ते निराहारस्य देहिनः ।
> > रसवर्जं रसोऽप्यस्य परं दृष्ट्वा निवर्तते ॥ ५९ ॥

> > Though the embodied soul may be restricted from sense enjoyment, the taste for sense objects remains. But, ceasing such engagements by experiencing a higher taste, he is fixed in consciousness.

from 2.59 control of sense can be obtained by controlling the tongue which stimulate desire. this can be done by fasting on ekadashi (niraharasya).

SB 11.8.21

> > tavaj jitendriyo na syad
> >  vijitanyendriyah puman
> > na jayed rasanam yavaj
> >  jitam sarvam jite rase

Although one may conquer all of the other senses, as long as the tongue is not conquered it cannot be said that one has controlled his senses. However, if one is able to control the tongue, then one is understood to be in full control of all the senses.

Comment: How is it answering the question? ***"this can be done by fasting on ekadashi (niraharasya)."*** <== This part is nowhere supported by scripture in your answer. Please edit and add proper citation.

Comment: विषया विनिवर्तन्ते निराहारस्य देहिनः । रसवर्जं रसोऽप्यस्य परं दृष्ट्वा निवर्तते  in this verse bhagavan clearly states that niraharasya for the all the sense consumer. that is what i meant 1. eyes control achieved by not seeing bad things 2. ear control achieved by not listening bad things 3. speech control is acheived by not speaking bad about others and self.  4. touch countol is achieved by not touching women 5. smell controll is atomatic not smelling bad. 6. but tounge controll is achieve by fasting.